# In JavaScript how to parse HTML string to convert to a tabular data (2d array)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, html-parsing

I like to parse the html string at clientside. We use React with TypeScript as frontend framework. While parsing the html, I also like to get styles associated with the element. It could be inline style, inherited from parent element or defined with some class in the style tag in head section (There is no external css file reference). Our goal is to parse the html string and convert it to a tabular format data with styles like backgroundColor, textColor, fontSize etc.

I know DOMParser can be used to parse the html string. And we can use hidden iFrame to load the html document and get the computed styles for each element.

I like to know if there any other library that can help us in this scenario? Also is there any alternate ways to get the styles without using iframe as we like to use web worker to compute the html parsing?

`Sample HTML string`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      li {
        color: red;
      }

      .highlight {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--StartFragment-->
    <h1>The ol and ul elements</h1>

    <h1>The ol and ul elements</h1>
    <p style="font-size: 16px">The ol element defines an ordered list:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>

    <p class="highlight">The ul element defines an unordered list:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    <h1>The table element</h1>

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Month</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--EndFragment-->
  </body>
</html>
```

After parsing the expected output will be an javascript object array in which each item will have text and style properties parsed from html string. Finally this 2d array will be processed and used to render as tabular structure.

[image]

Highly appreciate any help or guidance on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you need an iframe? you can just parse the document with DOMParser (basically having a non-mounted DOM) and then you can manipulate it as you wish, including reading the styles from it. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a little bit of DOM Manipulation and JS. I decided to implement this with JS, but this code can be easily modified to use with react. Consider the following code.

```js
function getDocumentFromString() {
  const sampleHtmlString = `
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      li {
        color: red;
      }

      .highlight {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--StartFragment-->
    <h1>The ol and ul elements</h1>

    <p style="font-size: 16px">The ol element defines an ordered list:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>

    <p class="highlight">The ul element defines an unordered list:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    <h1>The table element</h1>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Month</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--EndFragment-->
  </body>
</html>
`;

  const domParser = new DOMParser();
  const strDocument = domParser.parseFromString(sampleHtmlString, 'text/html');

  return strDocument;
}

function getInlineStyles(element) {
  const styles = Array.from(element.style);
  return styles.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(`${curr}:${element.style[curr]};`), '');
}

function getClassName(element) {
  return Array.from(element.classList).join(' ');
}

function parseHeading1(element) {
  return [
    {
      text: element.innerText,
      style: 'font-size:20px;font-weight:600'.concat(getInlineStyles(element)),
      className: getClassName(element),
    },
  ];
}

function parseParagraph(element) {
  return [
    {
      text: element.innerText,
      style: ''.concat(getInlineStyles(element)),
      className: getClassName(element),
    },
  ];
}

function parseOrderedList(element) {
  return Array(...element.children).map((child, idx) => ([
    {
      text: idx + 1,
      style: 'color:red'.concat(getInlineStyles(child)),
      className: getClassName(child),
    },
    {
      text: child.innerText,
      style: 'color:red'.concat(getInlineStyles(child)),
      className: getClassName(child),
    },
  ]));
}

function parseUnorderedList(element) {
  return Array(...element.children).map((child) => ([
    {
      text: child.innerText,
      style: 'color:red'.concat(getInlineStyles(element)),
      className: getClassName(child),
    },
  ]));
}

function parseTable(element) {
  const header = element.querySelectorAll('thead tr th');
  const body = element.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

  const headingElements = Array(...header).map(th => ({
    text: th.innerText,
    style: 'font-weight:600'.concat(getInlineStyles(th)),
    className: getClassName(th),
  }));
  const bodyElements = Array(...body)
    .map(tr => {
      const cells = Array(...tr.querySelectorAll('td'));
      return cells.map(cell => ({
        text: cell.innerText,
        style: ''.concat(getInlineStyles(cell)),
        className: getClassName(cell),
      }))
    });

  return [
    headingElements,
    ...bodyElements,
  ]
}

function convertElementsToTabular(elements) {
  const result = [];
  let noOfColumns = 1;
  Array(...elements).forEach(element => {
    switch (element.tagName) {
      case 'H1':
        result.push(parseHeading1(element));
        break;
      case 'P':
        result.push(parseParagraph(element));
        break;
      case 'OL':
        noOfColumns = Math.max(noOfColumns, 2);
        result.push(...parseOrderedList(element));
        break;
      case 'UL':
        result.push(...parseUnorderedList(element));
        break;
      case 'TABLE':
        result.push(...parseTable(element));
        break;
    }
  });

  console.log(result)
  return result;
}

function parseTableStructureToHtml(tableStructure) {
  const getTableCell = cell => `<td ${cell.style && 'style='.concat(cell.style)} ${cell.className && 'class='.concat(cell.className)}>${cell.text}</td>`;
  const getTableRow = row => `<tr>${row.map(getTableCell).join('')}</tr>`;
  const getTable = data => `<tbody>${data.map(getTableRow).join('')}</tbody>`;

  console.log(getTable(tableStructure))
  return `<table>
      <tbody>
        ${getTable(tableStructure)}
      </tbody>
    </table>`;
}

function main() {
  const strDocument = getDocumentFromString();
  const elementsOnScreen = strDocument.querySelector('body').children;
  const tableStructure = convertElementsToTabular(elementsOnScreen);
  
  const htmlStr = parseTableStructureToHtml(tableStructure);
  document.getElementById('main-container').innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

Let's go through the flow function-by-function.

**main** - this is the main method that calls other methods

**getDocumentFromString** - returns a DOM object based on the string passes to it. The resulting DOM is used for the rest of the processing.

**convertElementsToTabular** - Loops through all the elements present on the screen and uses the `tagName` of each element to determine how to process it.

Based on the `tagName`, different methods are called to process the element like  **parseHeading1**, **parseParagraph**, **parseOrderedList**, **parseUnorderedList** and **parseTable**.

If your use case contain even more types of tags (H2, H3, SPAN, etc), you just need to add more cases here and corressponding callbacks.

**parseHeading1**, **parseParagraph**, **parseOrderedList**, **parseUnorderedList**, **parseTable** -
These methods return an array containing the text to be displayed in the resulting table.
Each element contains -

1. `text`
2. `style` - it uses the `getInlineStyles` method to get styles from the sample string and also allows you to add your own to customize how tag looks.
3. `className` - uses the `getClassName` method to get the class names on the element from the sample string.

**parseTableStructureToHtml** - parses the array returned by `convertElementsToTabular` and returns a string containing tags for table rows and cells based on the data.

This html string is then inserted inside a div on the page to render it.

Hope this helps you!